# img tag in RichTextEditor Adobe AIR

Tags: air, richtextbox, tags, image

I wanted to insert an image into a RichTextEditor in AIR application. For my surprise I found this code working perfectly if the project was Web application but it doesn't work if I use it into AIR Desktop application. Here's the code

```
 <mx:RichTextEditor height="100%" width="100%">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
        <p>This is an image</p><p><img src='file:///C:/flag.png'></p>
        ]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:RichTextEditor>
<mx:Image source="file:///C:/flag.png" autoLoad="true"/>
```

The Image are loaded successfully in the "mx:Image" but not in the "mx:RichTextEditor". I have tried also to use "C:\flag.png", C:/flag.png" and "http://www.mysite.com/flag.png"

Could you please help me to figure out why I can insert an image into the RichTextEditor with Web application and not with AIR?

Many thanks,

Comment: I have tested that code in Flex 3.5 and flex 4.0 - AIR 2.0. And both gives me the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using AIR's HTML control instead to handle this.  Apparently TextField doesn't support loading images in AIR.  According to [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText):
*For AIR content in the application security sandbox, AIR ignores img tags in HTML content in ActionScript TextField objects. This is to prevent possible phishing attacks.*

There is also a bug on this with more info:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14238

Comment: Many thanks James for this useful information. I really appreciate your help.